# Django HTTPS settings: Why does setting both SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST and SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE break sessions?

Tags: python, django, session, cookies, https

I'm trying to lock my django app down to only HTTPS access. Everything seems to work fine if only SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST is True or if only SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE is True, but if both are True in my settings, then request.session becomes blank, breaking user authentication across the site.

I'm thinking this is because I have HTTP requests that redirect to HTTPS but trigger a session save before they do so, and that creates a new, overriding sessionid with an anonymous user because that HTTP request doesn't send the good sessionid cookie. I see this because the login form submission returns one sessionid cookie, but the redirection from http:.../home to https:.../home returns a new sessionid cookie value which is used from then on.

I might be fine removing SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST, but I'd like try to keep that functionality, and these http redirects are wasteful anyways.

First I tried adding the below in my wsgi.py from seeing this question - https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8964/trying-to-make-a-django-based-site-use-https-only-not-sure-if-its-secure

```
if not os.environ.get('DEVELOPMENT'):
  os.environ['HTTPS'] = 'on'
  os.environ['wsgi.url_scheme'] = 'https'
```

But django.shortcuts.redirect('/') and django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required still redirect with http instead of https after that, so that's very confusing...

If that's not the right way, then my only other thought is a custom implementation of SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST that only performs on HTTPS requests. Has anyone tried that before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it! I needed to set a setting to convince django that I am really on https even though I'm hiding behind nginx:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTOCOL', 'https')
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header