# Django sessions stop working after Redis implementation

Tags: python, django, session, redis

I Havve implemented redis using this [link](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/07/14/using-redis-as-django-session-store-and-cache-backend/) and after this session must bne stored in redis instaed of db. After configuration when I restart my app . I am getting hey error for my sessions.

e.g., 
Let say IN function `A` I declared a session and when I visit another link from browser and try to fetch same session in view the session is gone its not there. even no session keys exist . request.session.keys() is blank.

Here is my redis configuration:

## Cache server settings

```
REDIS_PROT = "redis://"
REDIS_HOST = "127.0.0.1"
REDIS_PORT = 6379
REDIS_DB = 0

REDIS_CACHE_SERVER = REDIS_PROT + REDIS_HOST + ":" + str(REDIS_PORT) + "/" + str(REDIS_DB)
REDIS_CACHEALOT_SERVER = REDIS_PROT + REDIS_HOST + ":" + str(REDIS_PORT) + "/" + str(REDIS_DB + 3)

DJANGO_REDIS_IGNORE_EXCEPTIONS = True

CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": REDIS_CACHE_SERVER,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "PARSER_CLASS": "redis.connection.HiredisParser",
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
            "COMPRESS_MIN_LEN": 10,
            "SOCKET_CONNECT_TIMEOUT": 5,  # in seconds
            "SOCKET_TIMEOUT": 5,  # in seconds
        }
    },
    "cachealot": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": REDIS_CACHEALOT_SERVER,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "PARSER_CLASS": "redis.connection.HiredisParser",
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
            "COMPRESS_MIN_LEN": 10,
            "SOCKET_CONNECT_TIMEOUT": 5,  # in seconds
            "SOCKET_TIMEOUT": 5,  # in seconds
        }
    }
}

# CacheALot service settings 

CACHALOT_ENABLED = True
CACHALOT_CACHE   = 'cachealot'

# Django Redis Session App Configuration 

SESSION_REDIS_HOST = REDIS_HOST
SESSION_REDIS_PORT = REDIS_PORT
SESSION_REDIS_DB = REDIS_DB + 4
#SESSION_REDIS_PASSWORD = 'password'
SESSION_REDIS_PREFIX = 'session'

SESSION_ENGINE = 'redis_sessions.session'
# If you prefer domain socket connection, you can just add this line instead of SESSION_REDIS_HOST and SESSION_REDIS_PORT.
#SESSION_REDIS_UNIX_DOMAIN_SOCKET_PATH = '/var/run/redis/redis.sock'

# Celery Configurations
REDIS_CELERY_BROKER_SERVER =  REDIS_PROT + REDIS_HOST + ":" + str(REDIS_PORT) + "/" + str(REDIS_DB + 1)
REDIS_CELERY_RESULT_SERVER = REDIS_PROT + REDIS_HOST + ":" + str(REDIS_PORT) + "/" + str(REDIS_DB + 2)

BROKER_URL = REDIS_CELERY_BROKER_SERVER
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = REDIS_CELERY_RESULT_SERVER
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=False
```

Any idea why I am getting key errors for django sessions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you're doing awfully much for simply enabling cached sessions. Why are you also using [django-redis-sessions](https://github.com/martinrusev/django-redis-sessions), [django-cachalot](https://github.com/BertrandBordage/django-cachalot) in addition to [django-redis](http://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/)?

Let's simplify with a minimal config, that works for me, using only [django-redis](http://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/). I'm following [their guide](http://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/#_user_guide), and [Django's documentation on setting up sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/#enabling-sessions) and [using cached sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/#using-cached-sessions):

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        }
    }
}
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'
```

That's it, test it by requesting a view and inspecting `request.session` or, if you're [outside of request, using your session store](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-out-of-views):

```
>>> from django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache import SessionStore
>>> s = SessionStore(session_key='ff882814010ccbc3c870523934fee5a2')
>>> s.save()
>>> s.session_key
'ff882814010ccbc3c870523934fee5a2'
>>> s.session_data
'KGRwMQpTJ19hdXRoX3VzZXJfaWQnCnAyCkkxCnMuMTExY2ZjODI2Yj...'
>>> s.get_decoded()
{'user_id': 42}
```

Comment: The issue because of which sessions were not working was below settings were set in settings file as son as I changed them to False everything seems to be working file.:

`CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True`

Comment: Didn't know you changed the default [for these](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-secure) (which is `False`); regardless, the solution I suggest above (using minimal config), is still correct. If you like, you may [refer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22430903/484127) to understand why these 2 settings interfere with your setup.

Comment: `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER` was enable on actual servers but on local it doesn't work since https not work on local , I delete the secure setting from local but forget about session and cookie setting . Anyway thanks to tell why they were conflicting

Comment: Good to hear your problem is resolved! :) If you don't think my answer helped you, please answer yourself and mark resolution